# How do I create a unit test where the answer needs to be rounded up?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm writing a unit test using the Google Test library. After I compile it I receive an error that says:

```
"Error: elevation which is:10 to be equal to:Z which is 9.999999999999999325"
```

How can I round up Z so the test can pass and be equal to 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach is not to round and test for exact equality, but to test for approximate equality. Google Test has `ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ` and `EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ`, which pass if two floats are neglibly different, and double versions of those macros, and `EXPECT_NEAR`, which allows you to specify the acceptable difference.

Documentation is [in gtest.h](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h#L2013).